# can we use <i:Interaction.Triggers> in WPF MVVM (not in Silverlight)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Can I use `<Interaction.Triggers />` in WPF MVVM rather than in Silverlight.

All the examples I have come across show the use of `<Interaction.Triggers />` in Silverlight.

How can I use it in WPF? I am using MVVM model.

Comment: Yes you can. What have you tried?

Answer (score 71):

Add a reference to the assembly System.Windows.Interactivity

then declare it in XAML as

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

or use it if you have Blend SDK installed

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

and use it in XAML as

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger>

    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: FWIW, v4 of that DLL can now be [pulled in via NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF) with `Install-Package System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF`

Comment: It's now [Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/open-sourcing-xaml-behaviors-for-wpf/).