# WPF TextBlock MouseUp Change ViewModel Property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I want to be able to click a `TextBlock` and my binding `IsEditing` to change.

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Description}" ToolTip="{Binding Description}" FontSize="12" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Visibility="{Binding IsEditing, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseUp">

            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TextBlock>
```

I'm fairly sure it goes in the `EventTrigger`.

I also need a `DataTrigger` in this `TextBlock` as well to change the visibility when `IsEditing` is false. I already have a converter for it.

I not certain where to look for this, could I have some help.

Comment: What you will need here is an attached behavior. I would recommend getting downloading `Mvvm light` via nuuget. This then allows you to open your project in blend and drag and drop the `EventToCommand` behavior onto your textblock allowing you to trigger a command on a click of the text block

Comment: would `MouseUp="{Binding MyMouseCommand}"` do it?

Comment: Yea sounds about right, you can then use the MyMouseCommand to do whatever you want. in blend once you have dropped the attached behavior onto your textblock there are tonnes of things you can change (trigger types, events, commands etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the nicest ways is to use Interactions (see [can we use <i:Interaction.Triggers> in WPF MVVM (not in Silverlight)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17750081/can-we-use-iinteraction-triggers-in-wpf-mvvm-not-in-silverlight) for set-up)

Then just add the following inside the text block:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseUp">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ChangeIsEditing}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Where ChangeIsEditing is a command in the DataContext / ViewModel to change `IsEditing` as required.