# MVVM WPF C# Auto-properties Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I would like to refactor my code a bit with Propertychanged.Fody as shown on this page http://www.mutzl.com/tag/mvvm-light/

Normal code:

```
private string _platformSelectedItem;
        public string PlatformSelectedItem
        {
            get { return _platformSelectedItem; }
            set
            {
                if (_platformSelectedItem == value) return;
                _platformSelectedItem = value;
                // Perform any pre-notification process here.
                GetData();
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

to

```
public string PlatformSelectedItem {get; private set}
```

The property is bounded to a Comboxbox and the values for the Combobox are dynamic based on another combobox, therefore I have my Method GetData().

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Platforms}" SelectedItem="{Binding PlatformSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="20" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,3,15.667,3"/>
```

If I refactor my code to autoproperties the method must be executed by click / open of the combobox.

Should I use a eventtrigger with command our is a more simpler way possible?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the thread [can we use <i:Interaction.Triggers> in WPF MVVM (not in Silverlight)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17750081/can-we-use-iinteraction-triggers-in-wpf-mvvm-not-in-silverlight)

My final solution looks:

ViewModel:

Properties area:

```
public RelayCommand SelectionChangedCommand { get; private set; }
```

Constructor:

```
SelectionChangedCommand = new RelayCommand(Update);
```

Method area:

```
   private void Update()
    {
        GetData();
    }
```

In my UI then:

```
  xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Platforms}" SelectedItem="{Binding PlatformSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="20" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,3,15.667,3">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </ComboBox>
```